# Error with Python3 on distroless image [No such file]

Tags: python-3.x, dockerfile, distroless

I'm using this dockerfile with flask :

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster

WORKDIR /python-docker

COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

It works fine, in my directory I have requirements.txt and a very simple app.py file :

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_geek():
    return '<h1>Hello from Flask & Docker</h2>'


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

I'd like to use it as a distroless image, so I build on this dockerfile :

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster as build-env

ADD / /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt

FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian10

COPY --from=build-env /app /app
COPY --from=build-env /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages
WORKDIR /app

ENV PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages

CMD [ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]
```

No error at build time, but when I run : **sudo docker run python-dockerdistro**

I get that error : **/usr/bin/python3.7: can't open file 'python3': [Errno 2] No such file or directory**

Do you have an idea of how resolve that error ? Thank you very much in advance

Comment: A small suggestion: If you are using python 3.8.10 as your build-env, I suggest to use FROM gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian11 which supports python-3.8.10. So your program will not generate any error i.e. because gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian10 has python-3.7 inside. It will break sometime due to mismatch of packages what you are going to use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) for the `gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian10` image is Python3:

```bash
$ docker image inspect -f '{{.Config.Entrypoint}}' gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian10
[/usr/bin/python3.7]
```

```
$ docker run --rm -it gcr.io/distroless/python3-debian10
Python 3.7.3 (default, Jan 22 2021, 20:04:44) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

However, your `CMD` is `[ "python3", "-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]`

You are essentially trying to run Python twice:

```bash
$ python3 python3
python3: can't open file '/tmp/python3': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Simply alter your `CMD` to only `["-m" , "flask", "run", "--host=0.0.0.0"]`